# It didn't last long

Tags: meaning

Could anyone explain what is the exact meaning for **Last Long**?
When to use this?

Comment: You'd better check a dictionary or tell us your findings. However, from Cambridge dictionary "not last long" means **to ​fail or be ​unsuccessful very ​soon**. E.g. You won't last ​long in ​your ​job if you ​carry on being so ​rude to the ​customers.

Comment: @Eilia - Everytime I opened my Inbox there was strange excitement. But most of the time it didn't last long......This is what I'm trying to ask...

Comment: It means continue for a short period.

Comment: If something *lasts long* it remains for a long time. Sod's Law says that if something is nice it does not usually last a long time.

Answer (score 9):

*Long* in the constructions *take long, last long, be long* -- all referring to extensive duration of an activity or event -- is a ***[Negative Polarity Item](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf)*** (NPI). That means

- *Take long, last long*, and *be long* are idiomatic; i.e, they don't follow ordinary rules.
  Synonymous phrases that **do** follow the normal rules are *take/last/be a long time*,
  which are **not** NPIs.
- They are all ungrammatical, **except** when appearing in the scope of a negative term.
  E.g:
  *This won't take long. ~ She isn't going to be long. ~ I doubt it lasts long* are all OK ...
  **but**
  **This will take long.* ~ **She's going to be long.* ~ **I think it lasts long* ... aren't.

There are a lot of negative words, like *doubt, forbid, prevent, seldom, only,* and *few* (but not ***a*** few), and even more negative constructions, like comparatives, questions, hypotheticals, etc. These are listed under "Negative Triggers" on the link above. They license the use of various NPIs (there are hundreds in English) within their scope. Notice the ungrammatical sentences resulting from removing the negative in the examples above.

**Executive summary:** *Last long* means the same thing as *last a long time*,
                                           except you can only say it in a negative context.

Answer (score 2):

This is worth a bit more than a GENREF response.

The adverb *long* is easily found {[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/long)} to have the sense

> **long** (23) –  for or during an extensive period of time: *long into the next
>   year*

here.

However, although we might well say

> The party lasted long into the night.

We wouldn't use the adverb without a 'complement' in a positive indicative sentence

> *The party lasted long.

Interrogative, and negative indicative sentences are acceptable:

> Did the party last long?
>
> The party didn't last long.

Answer (score 0):

"Didn't last long" means it's something which is there for a short period of time.

Some synonyms are **ephemeral, short-lived, brief, temporary, fleeting, transitory, transient, volatile, momentary, evanescent**(*mainly used in scientific excerpts*).